# Blender model file to java3D

Tags: blender

Can anyone please give me some advice on loading a blender model file into java3D without using blend2java, it doesn't work.

i do have a few java3D loaders for .3ds and .MS3D.

Thanks.

EDIT: 
java3d is out dated and not used. Try using jmonkeyengine 3.0 if you want to develop 3D games,
I just felt as though I should but this here to make this question somewhat useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-Blender-To-Create-Java3D-Models/) guide. I can't blame you for not wanting to use blend2java as there is almost no documentation or tutorials.